# Cpu fan speed running low

Tags: cpu, overheating, temperature, fancontrol

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Sometimes when I run a heavy process my CPU temperature reaches 90-95 Centigrade degree but fan speed is 4500RPM, sometimes I saw fan runs up to 5100RPM but at highest temperature it ever reached (95 Centigrade degree), It doesn't use the maximum speed it can. Why and How to fix it?
By the Way How bad is 95 Centigrade degree?
I use `ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X512FLC_R564FL` laptop.
My CPU: `Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8`
[98 degree but only 4500 rpm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SCJb.png)

Comment: ASUS motherboards have very good QFan Control in the BIOS. The issue is that they don't use the actual processor package temperature as the input to the fan control loop servo, and the difference can be significant. 12 degrees centigrade for my Prime Z490-A motherboard, under my test conditions. Demanding users need to compensate for this error. I do not know if ASUS laptops use the same fan control method. I do not let my processor go over 75 degrees Centigrade.

Comment: @DougSmythies I only have 2 Firefox tabs open and my CPU temperature is 72-78. I don't know what to do anymore. I had this problem in windows too.

Comment: @Mohammad Mahdi, if you haven't already install [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/installation/ubuntu.html)  or [thermald](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/thermald.8.html), you might want to give them a try. These two are the common apps used for power control/overheating. However, these are for generic heating issues, if yours is hardware related issues; there will be limitation on how much those apps can help.

Answer (score 0):

Note you can now choose a power profile in settings. Maybe choose high perf. for your case.

Balanced -> Performance

Comment: I tried, not only it doesn't increase the fan speed, but it also raises the CPU temperature

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is somewhat an old thread, but non the less here is my 2 cents. If you still have this machine, if you have the relevant skills you may need to open up the laptop housing. Physically inspect the the cooler, remove the cooler, thoroughly clean the cooler, remove any old thermal paste, reapply a quality thermal paste, reassemble your laptop,... Then follow everyone's advice here. (If the cooler was poorly installed from factory it will always cook up and would have probably gotten worse with the overheating), by tackling this task, you may solve the problem, but at the very least you will know if you are facing hardware or software issues.